# How can I convert a val to a fun when I use Jetpack Compose in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The Code A is from the official sample [project](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid).

I think I use a function instead of the `val background`, but the Code B is wrong.

How can I convert a `val` to a `fun` when I use `Jetpack Compose` in Kotlin?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun NiaApp(
    windowSizeClass: WindowSizeClass,
    appState: NiaAppState = rememberNiaAppState(windowSizeClass)
) {
    NiaTheme {
        val background: @Composable (@Composable () -> Unit) -> Unit =
            when (appState.currentDestination?.route) {
                ForYouDestination.route -> { content -> NiaGradientBackground(content = content) }
                else -> { content -> NiaBackground(content = content) }
            }

        background {
            Scaffold(
                ...
            ) { padding ->
                Row(
                   ...
                ) {
                  ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
@Composable
fun NiaApp(
    windowSizeClass: WindowSizeClass,
    appState: NiaAppState = rememberNiaAppState(windowSizeClass)
) {
    NiaTheme {
         @Composable
         fun background(aa: @Composable () -> Unit){
            when (appState.currentDestination?.route) {
                ForYouDestination.route -> { content -> NiaGradientBackground(content = content) }
                else -> { content -> NiaBackground(content = content) }
            }
        }

        background {
            Scaffold(
                ...
            ) { padding ->
                Row(
                   ...
                ) {
                  ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Added content:**

To Arpit Shukla: Thanks!

The Code C is based Code A `val background: @Composable (@Composable () -> Unit) -> Unit...` .

Your Code D is right, but why is Code C wrong ?

**Code C**

```
@Composable
fun Background(
    appState: NiaAppState,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    when (appState.currentDestination?.route) {
        ForYouDestination.route -> { content -> NiaGradientBackground(content = content) }
        else -> { content -> NiaBackground(content = content) }
    } 
}
```

**Code D**

```
@Composable
fun Background(
    appState: NiaAppState,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    when (appState.currentDestination?.route) {
        ForYouDestination.route -> NiaGradientBackground(content = content)
        else -> NiaBackground(content = content)
    }
}
```

**Added content again:**

To Arpit Shukla: Thanks!

By your way, Code E and Code F can't be compiled.

**Code E**

```
@Composable
fun Background(
    appState: NiaAppState,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    when (appState.currentDestination?.route) {
        ForYouDestination.route -> { content -> NiaGradientBackground(content = content) }
        else -> { content -> NiaBackground(content = content) }
    }(content) // Call the lambda
}
```

**Code F**

```
@Composable
fun Background(
    appState: NiaAppState,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit -> NiaGradientBackground(content = content)
) {
   when (appState.currentDestination?.route) {
        ForYouDestination.route -> { content -> NiaGradientBackground(content = content) }
        else -> { content -> NiaBackground(content = content) }
    }(content) // Call the lambda
}
```

**New content:**

To Arpit Shukla: Thanks!

By your way, Code G can't be compiled yet, I get the following error.

*@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function*

**Code G**

```
@Composable
fun Background(
    appState: NiaAppState,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    when (appState.currentDestination?.route) {
        ForYouDestination.route -> { content1: @Composable () -> Unit -> NiaGradientBackground(content = content1) }
        else -> { content1: @Composable () -> Unit -> NiaBackground(content = content1) }
    }(content) // Call the lambda
}
```

Comment: im not sure if i understood your question but i have to say converting a val into a function is not possible. instead you can say why you need to do this converting and ask for solution

Comment: Thanks!  I think Code B can do the same work

Comment: And Code A is hard to understand, so I hope to have a equivalent code.

Comment: Where you get `content`? Try to use `aa` instead.

Comment: What's so special about your background that it needs to be a `Composable` anyway? I see your background depends on `appState`. Still, I think you just need a function to return a background for you based on `appState` then you can use that background in your `Surface` or your `Scaffold` instead of wrapping everything inside an unnecessary `Composable` with a double lambda wrapped `Composable` just for your background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@Composable
fun NiaApp(
    windowSizeClass: WindowSizeClass,
    appState: NiaAppState = rememberNiaAppState(windowSizeClass)
) {
    NiaTheme {
        Background(appState) {
            Scaffold(
                ...
            ) { padding ->
                Row(
                   ...
                ) {
                  ...
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Background(
    appState: NiaAppState,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    when (appState.currentDestination?.route) {
        ForYouDestination.route -> NiaGradientBackground(content = content)
        else -> NiaBackground(content = content)
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Your `when` statement in Code C only creates a lambda function which when invoked will call the composables. You need to call that lambda too to see any effect:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Background(
    appState: NiaAppState,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
   when (appState.currentDestination?.route) {
        ForYouDestination.route -> { content -> NiaGradientBackground(content = content) }
        else -> { content -> NiaBackground(content = content) }
    }(content) // Call the lambda
}
```

Note: I haven't run this code but the compiler may give you an error here saying that it is unable to infer type for the `content` variable in the lambda. In that case you will have to explicitly provide the type: `content: @Composable () -> Unit -> NiaGradientBackground(content = content)`

Anyway, this is too much of unnecessary effort here and is only making the code more complex than the original one. Code D is much straightforward.

**Edit:** In code G, the lambda is by default not a composable function, you can't call composables inside it. Just putting `@Composable` in front of the lambda doesn't work, you need to explicitly provide the type for the entire `when` expression.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Background(
    appState: NiaAppState,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val background: @Composable (@Composable () -> Unit) -> Unit =
        when (appState.currentDestination?.route) {
            ForYouDestination.route -> { content -> NiaGradientBackground(content = content) }
            else -> { content -> NiaBackground(content = content) }
        }
    background(content)
}
```

We reached to the same code we started with which you wanted to simplify. Code D is the best solution in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: @HelloCW I have edited the answer. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content again in the question?

Comment: You had to specify the type in the when block, not the function definition. In your code E, change `ForYouDestination.route -> { content -> NiaGradientBackground(content = content) }` to `ForYouDestination.route -> { content: @Composable () -> Unit -> NiaGradientBackground(content = content) }`. Also whenever you get an error in code, do provide the error message along with the code.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my new content  in the question?

Comment: Voted up the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Your latest code is OK, but it's just like Code A :) .

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said, Code D is the answer for your question.

Comment: @HelloCW Any other doubt here?

Answer (score 1):

Well, something like this:

```
@Composable
fun NiaApp(
        windowSizeClass: WindowSizeClass,
        appState: NiaAppState = rememberNiaAppState(windowSizeClass) ) {
        NiaTheme {
            background(appState)() {
                Scaffold(
                    ...
                ) { padding ->
                  }
            }     
        }
}
    
@Composable
fun background(appState: NiaAppState): @Composable (@Composable () -> Unit) -> Unit =
        when (appState.currentDestination?.route) {
            ForYouDestination.route -> { content -> 
                NiaGradientBackground(content = content) }
                else -> { content -> NiaBackground(content = content) }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code can work, but it's also hard to understand, such as I use `background(appState)() {..}` to invoke the function.

Comment: And  more,  `background(appState) {..}` will cause error, and `background(appState)() {..} ` is correct, but it's hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

just cut your `Background` composable function and paste it outside of the `NiaApp` composable function

```
@Composable
fun NiaApp(
    windowSizeClass: WindowSizeClass,
    appState: NiaAppState = rememberNiaAppState(windowSizeClass)
) {
    NiaTheme {
        background {
            Scaffold(
                ...
            ) { padding ->
                Row(
                   ...
                ) {
                  ...
            }
        }
    }    
}

@Composable
fun background(aa: @Composable () -> Unit){
    when (appState.currentDestination?.route) {
        ForYouDestination.route -> { content -> 
            NiaGradientBackground(content = content) }
            else -> { content -> NiaBackground(content = content) }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But your code desn't work