# How can I invoke a function that returns a lambda which also accepts another lambda as its parameter ( () -> Unit ) -> Unit in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, android-jetpack-compose, higher-order-functions, function-call

The Code A is from the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74092059/how-can-i-convert-a-val-to-a-fun-when-i-use-jetpack-compose-in-kotlin) answered by Roman Y.

The Code A can work well when it invokes with `background(appState)() {...}`, why can't I remove parentheses ()?

But Code B fails when it invoke with `background(appState) {...}`, why?

And more Code C can work well when it invokes with  `val aa=background(appState)   aa{...}`, why?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun NiaApp(
        windowSizeClass: WindowSizeClass,
        appState: NiaAppState = rememberNiaAppState(windowSizeClass) 
) {
        NiaTheme {
            background(appState)() {
                Scaffold(
                    ...
                ) { padding ->
                  }
            }     
        }
}
    
@Composable
fun background(appState: NiaAppState): @Composable (@Composable () -> Unit) -> Unit =
        when (appState.currentDestination?.route) {
            ForYouDestination.route -> { content -> 
                NiaGradientBackground(content = content) }
                else -> { content -> NiaBackground(content = content) }
            }
```

**Code B**

```
@Composable
fun NiaApp(
        windowSizeClass: WindowSizeClass,
        appState: NiaAppState = rememberNiaAppState(windowSizeClass) 
) {
        NiaTheme {
            background(appState){
                Scaffold(
                    ...
                ) { padding ->
                  }
            }     
        }
}

...
```

**Code C**

```
@Composable
fun NiaApp(
        windowSizeClass: WindowSizeClass,
        appState: NiaAppState = rememberNiaAppState(windowSizeClass) 
) {
        val aa=background(appState)

        NiaTheme {
            aa{
                Scaffold(
                    ...
                ) { padding ->
                  }
            }     
        }
}

...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more of a `Kotlin` `function` question than a `Compose` one, so we will omit all `Jetpack Compose` related codes here, leaving only `Kotlin` related context to keep everything in focus.

Lets first define `key points` and mark them with a character.

- `Key point A`. Lambda invocaton : lambda `.invoke` is equal to `()`
- `Key point B`. Based on the [Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas)

> Passing trailing lambdas:
>
> According to Kotlin convention, if the last parameter of a function is a function, then a lambda expression passed as the corresponding argument can be placed outside the parentheses:
>
> ...
>
> If the lambda is the only argument in that call, the parentheses can be omitted entirely
>
> …

---

We'll make the background function look like this without the `@Composable` annotation and the `NiaAppState` arg, leaving it with **NO parameters**, but we will keep the function calls the same just so we're on track. I also named the returning lambda's parameter for a clearer picture.

```
fun background() : (anotherLambda: () -> Unit) -> Unit { ... }
```

> The Code A can work well when it invokes with background(appState)()
> {...}, why can't I remove parentheses ()?
>
> But Code B fails when it invoke with background(appState) {...}, why?

---

Let's break down your `CodeA` and `CodeB` at the same time to answer your 2 questions above. But remember, we are using **our own** **`background`** function and not the compose one.

> 1:
>
> Start first by a simple invocation, here we are just calling the background function, and disregarding
> the value that it returns, nothing unusual here

```
background()
```

> 2:
>
> While here, we are calling the background function, but also INVOKING
> the returned lambda (`Key point A`) **immediately**,
> we will get a compile error here '**No value passed for parameter anotherLambda**'
> because when we INVOKE it, it requires US to PASS an argument to it which is a type of `() -> Unit`

```
background()() // <-- compile error: No value passed for parameter anotherLambda
```

> 3: The Code A can work well when it invokes with background(appState)() {...}
>
> Here the compile error disappears when we specified the lambda block
> { ... } , because
>
> - We invoked the returned lambda (`Key point A`) **immediately**
> - And we supplied it with a lambda argument, and since the code follows `Key point B`  it worked by simply calling the argument lambda's block { ... }

```
background()() {
   ...
}
```

> 4: But Code B fails when it invoke with background(appState) {...}, why?. Why can't I remove parentheses ()?
>
> Here, we'll get another kind of error, '**Too many arguments for public fun
> background() ...**'.
>
> Because we are NOT INVOKING the returned lambda, we are simply calling the background() function itself and it doesn't have any lambda parameters or any parameters at all, check the background function signature we did above and `Key point B`.
>
> And your actual background function has only one parameter (appState: NiaAppState) and it's not a lambda type parameter, again check `Key point B`.

```
background() {  // big chunk of compile error here: Too many arguments for public fun background() ...
   ...
}
```

> 5:
>
> This is the version (check #3) **without** `Key point B`. We invoke the
> returned lambda (`Key point A`) **immediately**  and pass a lambda argument **inside** of it.

```
background () ( {
   ...
} )
```

Equivalent `background()` calls using the lambda's `invoke()`
instead of a parenthesis `()`:

```
// #2
background().invoke() // <-- compile error: No value passed for parameter anotherLambda

// #3
background().invoke {
   ...
}

// #4
background(invoke { // big chunk of compile error here: Too many arguments for public fun background() ... and Unresolved reference invoke
   ...
} )

// #5
background().invoke ( {
    ...
} )
```

---

> And more Code C can work well when it invokes with val
> aa=background(appState)   aa{...}, why?

Finally lets break down `CodeC`:

> 1:
>
> Here we call the background function, and because we have an
> assignment operation with the type inferred, `aa` is now the returned lambda value from background()
> invocation

```
val aa = background()

// your actual background function equivalent
val aa = background(appState)
```

> 2:
>
> Assignment declaration with specified type.

```
// aa assignment declaration with type specified
val aa : (() -> Unit) -> Unit = background()

// your actual background function equivalent
val aa : @Composable (@Composable () -> Unit) -> Unit  = background(appState)
```

> 3:
>
> Assignment declaration with specified type and with a defined name for aa's lambda parameter.

```
// aa assignment declaration with type specified and named parameter
val aa : (aaLambdaParam : () -> Unit) -> Unit = background()

// your actual background function equivalent
val aa : @Composable (aaLambdaParam: @Composable () -> Unit) -> Unit  = background(appState)
```

> 4:
>
> `aa` is the returned lambda that accepts an argument of type `() -> Unit` and because of `Key point B`, we can omit the parenthesis and directly call the block {...} of the passing lambda argument

```
aa {
   ...
}
```

> 5:
>
> But if we call it this way, we'll get an error, 'No value passed for parameter ...', because `aa` is now a function that expects an argument of type `() -> Unit`, see `Key point A`.

```
aa() // <-- No value passed for parameter 'p1' (#2) or 'No value passed for parameter 'aaLambdaParam' (#3)
```

> 6:
>
> This is the version (check #4) **without** `Key point B`. We invoke the lambda (`Key point A`) and pass a lambda argument inside of it.

```
aa ( {
   ...
} )
```

Equivalent `aa` calls using the lambda's `invoke()`
instead of a parenthesis `()`:

```
// #4, Key point B
aa.invoke {
   ...
}

// #5
aa.invoke() // <-- No value passed for parameter 'p1' or 'aaLambdaParam'

// #6, not Key point B
aa.invoke( {
   ...
} )
```

I would suggest re-visiting [Kotlin's High-Order Functions and Lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is a higher order function question, this sample will be easier to understand

```
fun getResult(): (innerLambda: () -> Int) -> Unit = { innerLambda ->
    println(innerLambda())
    println("result")
}
```

The innerLambda will return a number, so when we call the function getResult

```
getResult() // this is type (innerLambda: () -> Int) -> Unit
```

the second parentheses is `invoke` function, so

```
getResult().invoke()
getResult()()
```

those two line is same, and when we get here, we have to pass the `innerLambda` in, so it will look like

```
getResult()({ 100 })
```

at this moment, ide will prompt you `Lambda argument should be moved out of parentheses` , like this

```
getResult()(){ 100 }
```

the version A result

And for the version C is simple, using a variable to curried a function is common in functional programming, call curried function, so when we figure out the version A, we can check out the following code

```
val getApiResult:(innerLambda: () -> Int) -> Unit = getResult()
getApiResult.invoke({ 100 })
```

same step like previous sample, move lambda out

```
getApiResult.invoke(){ 100 }
```

**when lambda is last parameter we can remove unnecessary parentheses**

```
getApiResult.invoke { 100 }
getApiResult() { 100 }
```

those two line is same, and remember in Kotlin, **when lambda is last parameter we can remove unnecessary parentheses, AGAIN**, eventually we got this

```
getApiResult { 100 }
```

add some sample related to above answer

```
class InnerLambda:Function0<Int> {
    override operator fun invoke(): Int {
        return 100
    }
}

fun clickListener(event:() -> Unit) {

}
clickListener {

}
```

the operator fun is common used, like `+` is `unaryPlus`, those are Kotlin syntax sugar, so `3.unaryPlus(5)` is equal to  `3 + 5` in Kotlin, that is why `invoke` can be replace with `()`

[image]

Comment: The different between b and c is, in version c `getApiResult` is executed, we got the result and run next line, but version b, if you remove a parentheses, the `getResult(){100}` is be compile into `getResult({100})`, which is wrong format, check it with **Kotlin bytecode** is cleaner